# Unable to assign position to offsetTop

Tags: javascript

I have div element "y" and a class of images called "terrain". The below code is intended such that whenever an element of the class is clicked, y and that element share top and left positions.
However, it doesn't seem to be working. What is the solution?

```
var lands = document.getElementsByClassName("terrain");
for(var i = 0; i < lands.length; i++){
    lands[i].onclick = function(){
        y.style.left = lands[i].offsetLeft;
        y.style.top = lands[i].offsetTop;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/2401386) so that the currentely iterated "terrain" sets its properties (offsetLeft, offsetTop) to y, when its clicked.

Hope this helps:

```
var lands = document.getElementsByClassName('terrain');
for (var i = 0; i < lands.length; i++) {
  (function (land) {
    land.onclick = function () {
      alert('left: '+land.offsetLeft+' top: '+land.offsetTop);
      y.style.left = land.offsetLeft + 'px';
      y.style.top = land.offsetTop + 'px';
    };
  }) (lands[i]);
}
```

Comment: Do you see some alert? If yes the click-handler works but I can not test offsetLeft/offsetTop.

Comment: I'm testing it now

Comment: I see an alert.

Comment: Are ther values "'left: 34 top: 57"? If no, then those terrains do not have got offsetLeft/offsetTop.

Comment: The alert is there still, but the position of "y" doesn't change.

Comment: The values in the alert change depending upon which element of "terrain" is clicked.

Comment: Does it change its position now?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop messes up the **closure** you have (the varaible `i` inside the click handler will have the same value for all the `lands` when one of them is clicked, the value of `i` will be `lands.length` which is an undefined value). That's happening because the scope of `for` remain the same untill the end. You need something that creates a different scope for each item of the `lands` array. `forEach` can acheive that like this:

```
var lands = document.getElementsByClassName("terrain");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(lands, function(land) {
    land.onclick = function(){
        y.style.left = land.offsetLeft;
        y.style.top = land.offsetTop;
    };
});
```

Since `lands` (the result of `getElementsByClassName`) is an **array-like object** but not an **array**, `forEach` is not defined, so we have to call it like this: `Array.prototype.forEach.call`. Read more about: [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [**call**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).